# Best way to return HTML table from cffunction in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, coldfusion

I have cffunction where I build my HTML table. I would like to return HTML table and output in div container. Here is example of my JQuery Ajax call:

```
var divID = $('#container');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Components/MyCFC.cfc?method=getTable',
    data: {'keyVal':keyVal,'userVal':userVal},
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS == 200){
        divID.empty(); //first clear the div content
        divID.append(obj.DATA); //Here table should be appended

        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Coldfusion function:

```
<cffunction name="getTable" access="remote" output="true" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="keyVal" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="userVal" type="numeric" default="1">

    <cfset fnResults = StructNew()>

    <cfif Len(arguments.userVal) AND Len(arguments.keyVal)>
        <cfquery name="userRecords" datasource="Test">
            //My SQL Query
        </cfquery>

        <cfset fnResults.recordcount = userRecords.recordcount>

        <table class='myTbl'>
            <caption>Records: <cfoutput>#userRecords.recordcount#</cfoutput></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    ...     
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <cfloop query="userRecords">
                    <cfoutput>
                    <tr id="#trim(Some field)#">
                        <td>#trim(Some field)#</td>
                        ...
                    </tr>
                    </cfoutput>
                </cfloop>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <cfset fnResults.data = //Here I want to dump my table>
        <cfset fnResults.status = "200">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset fnResults.message = "ERROR">
        <cfset fnResults.status = "400">
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn fnResults>
</cffunction>
```

I haven't used this method in any of my applications before. My guess is that I will have to change return type of my function to Plain or something else. Also in JQuery I will have to replace JSON type with HTML. What I'm not sure about is if I can keep my structure in `cffunction` or I have to organize my function differently. What is the best method to return HTML content to client side? Is that better approach or returning data and building table on the client side with JQuery/Javascript? Please if you have any suggestions let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: In your cffunction, use cfsavecontent to generate an html string.  Then you can simply output it.  The js part of the equation is innerHTML.

Comment: Also, you have returnFormat set to 'JSON' and you are trying to output HTML in the body of the function (instead of returning it from the function as Dan noted).